# Dependency injection and contextual dependency injection

Tags: jakarta-ee

i don't know what is dependency injection .Is there any difference between dependency injection and contextual dependency injection .Can any one help me

Comment: I don't know why my answer has been deleted. Anyway I just briefly explained the concept and suggested you to check this link http://lowcoupling.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/dependency-injection/ to have a more detailed explanation. Regards